# This requires a comma, correct?

Tags: punctuation, commas

> He jumped down, creating a cloud of dust.

I think it's just because the sentence is so short that it looks odd with a comma, but grammatically speaking, that comma is necessary, right?

Comment: yes             fasdf15char

Comment: Say the sentence out loud, do you pause in the middle of the sentence, if so, where? Personally, I would read the sentence as _"He jumped down `*pause*` creating a cloud of dust"_, so I would include a comma right there.

Comment: *Grammatically* speaking, no punctuation is necessary at all. No capitalization, either. And you could use the Cyrillic alphabet, or Katakana.

Answer (score 1):

You need the comma, as you are combining an independent clause with a participial clause.

"creating a cloud of dust" is a present participle phrase describing a noun (or in this case, a pronoun).

Answer (score 1):

Stylistically, you would need a comma in there. But grammatically the sentence would be fine. Even in style, a comma in that kind of sentence is something optional.

Answer (score 0):

Yes; a comma is required as you have placed it in that sentence.

Answer (score 0):

"creating a cloud of dust" is a subordinate clause so you need that comma in order to give the  grammatical error free sense.